# the way to listen the Worker's event in Clustor module in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I'm using clustor module to do multiple process application. I want to listen the event of Worker, the example in the document is like this:

```
cluster.fork().on(‘listening’,cb);
```

But I want to take apart the worker and master, so in my worker.js file, I write like this:

```
const http = require(‘http’);
const cluster = require(‘cluster’);
const worker = cluster.worker;
http.createServer((req,res)=>{
   res.writeHead(200);
   res.end(“hello world”);
}).listen(8099);
worker.on(‘listening’,address=>{
  console.log(address:${address});
});
```

But the listening callback will not run, so does it mean I can only listen the Worker's event in master.js?